# zählen oder abzählen

Tags: difference, meaning-in-context

Was ist der Unterschied zwischen diesen Sätzen?

> Die Anwesenden zählen.
>
> Die Anwesenden abzählen.

Wenn man eine Frage stellen will, kann man die folgenden Fragen verwenden?

> Wie viele Äpfel hast du gezählt? - Ich habe 10 Äpfel gezählt.
>
> Wie viele Äpfel hast du abgezählt? - Ich habe 10 Äpfel abgezählt.

Answer (score 3):

Wann immer man etwas abzählt, zählt man es auch.

*Abzählen* wird meistens gebraucht im Sinne von "sicherstellen, dass es sich um eine bestimmte Zahl handelt." Wenn ich die Äpfel abzähle, bedeutet das üblicherweise, dass ich vor dem Kunden einen nach dem anderen einpacke, sodass wir sehen, dass es so viele sind, wie er bestellt hat. Wenn ich die Äpfel zähle, schaue ich nur, wie viele es sind.

Wenn ich die Anwesenden abzähle, sollte ich also schon ungefähr wissen, wie viele es sein sollen.